# stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file

Tags: php, ios, sockets, ssl

I'm implementing iOS Push Notifications with PHP and for the last couple of hours I've been struggling with this error `stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file`.
I've already came across various related issues in SO but none helped me so far.

Anyway I made an interesting finding.
This is my code:

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->sslPem);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $this->passPhrase);

$this->apnsConnection = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error,
    $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

var_dump($this->apnsConnection);
```

Outputs:
`stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file`

But the moment I remove the protocol (`ssl://`) from the Address to the socket to connect to, it connects successfully.

```
$this->apnsConnection = stream_socket_client('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error,
    $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

var_dump($this->apnsConnection);
```

Outputs:
`resource(93, stream)`

How and why does it happen this way?